# Class admin does not exist? Route::group Issue

Tags: php, laravel

I found this issue when I add 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin'] into

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware'=> ['auth' => 'admin']],
```

and it show me "the Class admin does not exist"

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Comment: show us your `App\Http\Kernel.php`, specifically `$routeMiddleware`

Comment: Alright. So need to do add for admin?

Comment: yep, you need to add `admin` to your `$routeMiddleware` before using it to your routes.

Comment: Also, `'middleware'=> ['auth' => 'admin']` should probably be `'middleware'=> ['auth', 'admin']` instead.